# Python: Getting key error in though key exist, Azure API

Tags: python, json, string, rest, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to use Azure API and get resources. The response is a big JSON.

```
{
...
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_name>/resourceGroups/<resouce_group_name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VM_name>",
    "name": "<VM_name>",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "location": "eastus",
    "tags": {}
},
...
}
```

I'm saving the response in the modified form in a dictionary (in a variable named self.resources, I'm using classes) where the key is `id` and value is `{'name': response['name'], 'type': response['type']}`

something like,

```
{
  '/subscriptions/<subscription_name>/resourceGroups/<resouce_group_name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VM_name>': 
                 {
            'name': response['name'],
            'type': response['type']
                 }
}
```

however, when I try to access a key in the self.resources in another method, it gives me a key error for 528 keys out of 1345.

I can confirm the key is present because I can see it in the JSON file that is written after the response is fetched.

I even tried reading from that JSON file instead of using `self.resources` but still, the error persists.

what could be the reason for this?
I'm using python 3.8, windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue, and it was a really silly problem, actually I was using two APIs as I said, one was to fetch resources and the other API was for alerts, both had resource ID but in the alerts one the virtual machine names were in caps.

I confirmed it because I didn't compared word by word, but only did search using VS code find option and it is not case-sensitive.

I hope it solves issue of anyone struggling with the IDs.